# Make multiple row of three dependent dropboxes

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I built three dependent dropboxes: supplayer (supplier), kode_barang (ItemID), and nama_barang (variant). User can select a supplier, then choose an ItemID provided by that supplier, then decide which variant of product from the ItemID he want. I use this script:

```
window.load=$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'supplayerAjaxData.php',
        success:function(html){
            $('#supplayer').html(html);
        }
    }); 
});  


$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#supplayer').on('change',function(){//change function on country to display all state 
        var kode_supplayer = $('#supplayer').val();
        if(kode_supplayer){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                data:'kode_supplayer='+kode_supplayer,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#kode_barang').html(html);
                    $('#nama_barang').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#kode_barang').html('<option value="">Select country first</option>');
            $('#nama_barang').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
        }
    });

    $('#kode_barang').on('change',function(){//change state to display all city
        var kode_barang = $('#kode_barang').val();
        if(kode_barang){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                data:'kode_barang='+kode_barang,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#nama_barang').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#nama_barang').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
        }
    });
});
```

Then I show it in this way:

```
<table id="theTable" border="1">

<thead><br><br>
    <tr>
        <th> Supplayer </th>
        <th> Kode Barang </th>
        <th> Nama Barang </th>
        <th> Quantity </th>
    <tr> 
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select class="selectpicker form-control" name="supplayer[]" id="supplayer" autofocus="autofocus" required>
                <option value="">Select an Option</option>                            
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="selectpicker form-control" name="kode_barang[]" id="kode_barang"  autofocus="autofocus" required>
                <option value="">Select an Option</option>                            
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="selectpicker form-control" name="nama_barang[]" id="nama_barang" standard title="Select an Option" autofocus="autofocus" required>
                <option value="">Select an Option</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input class="valOne" type="text" name='qty[]'></td>
    </tr>
```

Until this point, everything works perfectly. Then I make second row by copying the first row literlally from `<tr>` to `</tr>`, but it's not working. Selected value in the second row appears in the first row instead. Would you please help me to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Because id of all the dropdowns will be same for row 1 and row 2.

Comment: @Lalit how I fix it? Can I just add number like'supplayer1' in the second row? I'm sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: Yes you can give ids like "supplayer_1", "kode_barang_1","nama_barang_1" for first row and  "supplayer_2", "kode_barang_2","nama_barang_2" for second row.

Comment: @Lalit then, is there any changes I need to do to my script?

Comment: How you are generating rows in html table?

Comment: I'm planning to do it manually. I need three rows per page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158929/discussion-between-lalit-and-david).

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding rows manually then giving different IDs should work and you would have to listen for them individually however i would not do it this way.

I'd rather add an `onchange` attribute to `select`, assign a function and then do the work

**HTML:**

```
<select onchange="supplierChanged(this)">
    <option>Option 1</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
function supplierChanged(elem) {
    var selectValue = $(elem).val();
    // Rest of your code
}
```

**Update 1**

```
$('.supplayer').on('change',function(){
  //change function on country to display all state 
  // change 'id' - supplayer to 'class' - supplayer
        var self = this; // maintaining reference of 'this' so as to use in other functions
        var kode_supplayer = $(self).val();

        // Not sure about these two below (not tested), you need to test them
        var kode_barang = $(self).closest(".kode_barang")[0];
        var nama_barang = $(self).closest(".nama_barang")[0];

        if(kode_supplayer){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                data:'kode_supplayer='+kode_supplayer,
                success:function(html){
                    $(kode_barang).html(html);
                    $(nama_barang).html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $(kode_barang).html('<option value="">Select country first</option>');
            $(nama_barang).html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
        }
    });
```

Comment: It's not working. There is no data get populated from the supplayer dropdown.